# Bounding the difference of random variables by coupling.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have two probability densities differing by atmost $\delta$. Is it possible to use coupling to have two random variables with the above two densities differing by less than $\delta$?

I also have that the densities are differentiable k times with all the derivatives being Lipschitz continuous.
And the densities have compact support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not without further conditions.  For example, maybe the random variables are spread out over such large intervals that their densities are 
always less than $\delta/2$.

EDIT:   Consider densities
$$\eqalign{f(x) &= \cases{1/2 & for $0 \le x < 1/2$ or $1 \le x < 3/2$\cr
                  0 & otherwise\cr}\cr
 g(x) &= \cases{1/2 + \delta & for $0 \le x < 1/2$\cr
                1/2 - \delta & for $1 \le x < 3/2$\cr
                0 & otherwise\cr}}$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with these densities, $P(X \ge 1) = 1/2$ while $P(Y \le 1/2) > 1/2$, so no matter how small $\delta$ is, $P(X - Y \ge 1/2) > 0$.

These densities are discontinuous at $0, 1/2, 1, 3/2$, but it's easy to construct similar examples that are smooth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also have that the densities are differentiable $k$ times with all the derivatives being Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: And the densities have compact support.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's helpful.